# How to set gRPC keepalive in Dart client

Tags: dart, grpc

How can I adjust the keepalive parameters for a Dart gRPC client?

There is a page defining keepalive options: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md.

It describes these as "channel arguments".

I've seen examples of this being done in Python, for example here: https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~mxia3/2019/02/23/Using-gRPC-in-Production/

When creating a channel in Dart I use `ChannelOptions()`, which supports named parameters `credentials`, `idleTimeout` and `backOffStrategy`, e.g.

```dart
client = ClientChannel(
       'localhost',
        port: 50051,
        options: ChannelOptions(
          credentials: credentials,
          //idleTimeout: Duration(minutes: 1),
          //backOffStrategy: backOffstrategy
        ));

  }
```

How or where do I set the channel arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gRPC keepalive is not yet implemented. There's a tracking issue to [add KeepAlive support](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/issues/157) you can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE ON JUNE 22, 2023

Keepalive has been implemented to Grpc dart

for more information check below pull request

[grpc-dart keepalive pull request](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/pull/634)